# Danger of overlay scrollbar in Natty

Tags: 11.04, overlay-scrollbars

At first I liked the new scroll bar on Natty, but it is prone to accidental clicks.
See for instance the screenshot below:

[image: Natty scroller]

It is easy to click "Remove" as the scroller fades out, or before it appeared, or when it fails to appear. I accidentally removed a Startup App because of this.

Is it to avoid this danger while still using overlay scrollbars?
Maybe something that would make nearby background dialogs unclickable?

Comment: best advice... uninstall them :D

Comment: Unfortunately Canonical haven't fully grasped that true design puts usability above all else and pretty as the overlays are, and as rarely as most of us use scrollbars because of the ubiquity of the wheel, the overlay scrollers have a multitude of problems.

Comment: Is there even a question here? Anyway, never click something that is not solid, if you click on a faded scrollbar (at the rightmost part of if, as well!) it is not exactly their fault if you make a mistake, is it? 

overlay scrollbars are nicely done and the changes coming in 11.10 will make them even better

Comment: @Charles: Unfortunately half of the time I can't use my wheelmouse and only have an unreliable tiny TrackPoint. @Chriskin: I am sure many users have the same problem. It is easy to blame users, but since Ubuntu is open source I guess some people have started fixing this problem somehow.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best is to click on the left side of scroll bars always :D

Also they should implement a **Snapping feature**, once the scroll bar is snapped then there should be indication/color change